# Calculate max(num) +1 with calculated value? (Help please)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I want to do this:

- MANUEL 1
- PEPE   1
- MANUEL 2
- LUIS   1

I want to get the number by a calculated value, but if the name is duplicated get the `max(num)+1`.

Example:

```
if (NEW.INPUT) exist 
    find max(num) where (NEW.INPUT)=(STRING IN THE LIST)
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You need to use a Calculated column, try searching through the   https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculated-column?tab=Newest or https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculated-column-formula?tab=Newest tags for inspiration

Answer (score 1):

In calculated columns we can refer to other columns, but not other rows. A common solution would be to create a master list that had the names and current number. (so each name would only exist once on this list. You could then create a workflow that runs for each new item on the original list that tries to find the item in the master list and increments the number if found, or, adds a new item if not found. The workflow could then update the field in the original list with the current max value for that name.

It's a bit complex to get this working really well, to take things like deletes or name changes into account.

Another option is a code-based event handler, or a custom form with javascript to query the list, find the count of matching items, and update the field on the form.

Comment: There not't something like an after event  of Microsoft aacess but with the list? I tried to create this linking the tables but seems like liked tables can't have events.

Comment: That's what workflows and event handlers are: after events. Workflows are created without code using a designer, event handlers are code written using visual studio.